# Haskell and Parsec: Parsing two separated lists of numbers

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I've been experimenting with Parsec for the first time in my life and I found a task that turned out surprisingly difficult.

I want to parse two lists of numbers separated by `|` character.
Here's an example:

`Data 1: 43 76 123 98 32 | 32 88 43 123 43`

Here's the code I've come up so far

```hs
data Data = Data Int [Int] [Int]
    deriving Show

toInt :: String -> Int
toInt = read

parseRow :: Parser Data
parseRow = do
    _ <- Parsec.string "Data"
    _ <- Parsec.spaces
    cid <- toInt <$> many1 Parsec.digit
    firstList <- map toInt <$> between (Parsec.string ": ") (Parsec.char '|') (many1 (many1 Parsec.digit <* Parsec.space))
    secondList <- map toInt <$> sepBy1 (many1 Parsec.digit) (Parsec.char ' ')
    return $ Data cid firstList secondList
```

It gets confused while parsing `firstList`. I guess I messed up parsing the spaces separating the numbers, but can't see an obvious mistake.

Going forward, what's the most beginner-friendly introduction to Parsec? I found a few tutorials, but happy to hear recommendations.

Comment: Toss `Parsec.spaces` on a new line between the bindings of `firstList` and `secondList`.

Comment: What Daniel said. My suggestion works for parsing the specific string in question and when you would have the exact same spacing for all input, but I would do it more generally for code that I would actually use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Parsec.char '|'` with `Parsec.string "| "` in `firstList`.  Otherwise, `secondList` has to deal with an extra space at the beginning of the input that it doesn't expect.

Comment: Thanks for comment. This still fails with the error "Unexpected ' ', expecting a digit" right after the `|` character. I'll experiment with the code later today and will update my code.

Comment: Are you sure you included the space after the bar?  It parsed for me when I tried it.  I.e., `"| "`, not `"|".`

Comment: I could have made something wrong, as I was in a rush before work. I'll have more time in about 5h and I'll give it a go. Thanks for confirming that it works for you.

Comment: Sorry for a delay, I got sick and had to postpone the parsing. It works as expected, the error I faced was caused by another line, which contained more spaces between numbers. This was a separate issue and easy to adjust. Thanks for the help with this problem.